# UNC Network Path issues with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Omitted sensitive data.

I can't get PowerShell to connect to a shared folder.
    `Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\Software\Crystal Reports\CRRedist2005_X64.msi' because it does not exist.`

This does work on one machine but not another.

```
$source = "\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\Software\Crystal Reports\CRRedist2005_X64.msi"
Copy-Item $source -Destination $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads -Verbose
```

This doesn't work on either machine

```
Copy-Item "\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\Software\Crystal Reports\CRRedist2005_X64.msi" -Destination $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads -Verbose
```

I've tried using the New-PSDrive method

```
    New-PSDrive -Name S -Root "\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\" -PSProvider FileSystem
Copy-Item "S:\Software\Crystal Reports\CRRedist2005_X64.msi" -Destination $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads -Verbose
```

Gives `The specified drive root "\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.`

The FileSystem:: also gives path not found

```
Copy-Item "FileSystem::\\192.168.0.000\Common Data\Software\Crystal Reports\CRRedist2005_X64.msi" -Destination $env:USERPROFILE\Downloads -verbose
```

If I copy the address into file explorer it works no problems.

I'm going to crazy trying to figure out why it's not working.

Edit: Remapped the drives and it worked on the second computer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! You should tell us what you've tried to fix this problems, and try to find a way that we can reproduce it! Since it works on one and not the other. (Although, I can appreciate the difficulty of that in this case). Also - you can make the inline-code parts of your question look nice by enclosing it in backticks (`).

Comment: How are you connecting to the other machine, Could it be the [double-hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) problem?